# How to call directive on radio button to set value in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to set some default value to radio button, as per the value particular radio button should be selected. For this I created a directive radioControlDir in (controlDirectives.js) file.

```
function controlDir()
{
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          ngModel: '=',
          queObj: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs)
        {
          if(angular.isUndefined(scope.ngModel))
          {
              scope.ngModel = 'Y';
          }
        }
    };
}
```

scope.queObj._pageAttributes.defaultValue has value that will be set if ngmodel do not have value.  Other directive for text and select is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just because you have the restrict value 'E' which means element.

It should be 'A' (attribute);

And in the plunker the `queObj._pageAttributes.defaultValue` is "", but for radio you need set it to the value for this radio like 'Y';

```
function radioControlDir()
    {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
              ngModel: '=',
              queObj: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs)
            {

              if(angular.isUndefined(scope.ngModel))
              {

                scope.ngModel = 'Y';
              }
            }
        };
    }
```